# Every continuous open mapping $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotonic

Tags: general-topology, continuity, monotone-functions, open-map

> Prove that every continuous open mapping from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is monotonic

I want to prove it only (or mostly) using arguments and concepts from topology, and not from analysis.

I don't have anything that I think is useful or correct yet. The only idea I had was this:

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and open. If $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $x<y$, then $(x,y)$ is connected and open. Since $f$ is open, $f(x,y)$ must be open, and since $f$ is continuous, $f(x,y)$ must be connected. This way, if I managed to prove that $f(x,y)$ is bounded, then we would have $f(x,y)=(a,b)$ for some $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. Now, because $f$ is continuous and open, we would have that $f(\partial(x,y))=\partial(a,b)$, that is, $\{f(x),f(y)\}=\{a,b\}$, which implies that $f(x)=a, f(y)=b$, or $f(x)=b, f(y)=a$ and finally $f(x)<f(y)$ or $f(x)>f(y)$.

However, I don't know how to prove that $f(x,y)$ is bounded, and even if I did it, I think this would only establish that f is injective, not that it is monotone.

I would be thankful if you could give me some hints (not full solutions).

Comment: Have you learned about compactness yet?

Comment: How do you know that $f(\partial(x,y))=\partial(a,b)$? The property $f(\partial U)=\partial f(U)$ needs not hold for an open continuous function $f$ on a general metric space (or even on $\mathbb{R}^2$).

Comment: @Joe I know the basic definitions and results, but I haven't gone much beyond that yet.

SangchulLee: Sorry, my mistake. I misread a theorem.

Comment: $[x,y]$ is compact, so it’s image under $f$ will be also, which in $\mathbb{R}$ means it’s closed and bounded.

Comment: As for the proof, you may first prove that $f : \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is monotone if the following property holds: $$\forall x<z<y \ : \ \min\{f(x),f(y)\} \leq f(z) \leq \max\{f(x),f(y)\}.$$ This can be done purely by using the ordering of $\mathbb{R}$. Then you may use this to show that a continuous function cannot be open if it is not monotone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: Supose that $f$ is not monotonic, then exist a interval $[x,y]$ and a point $t \in (x,y)$, such that $f(t)= \max_{s \in [x,y]}{f(s)}$ or $f(t)= \min_{s \in [x,y]}{f(s)}$. Once you have that, study the set $f((x,y))$.